# Messages are not requeue-ing on thrown exception

Tags: spring-integration

I am using

**Spring Integration 4.1.2.RELEASE**

**Spring AMQP 1.4.3.RELEASE**

When an exception is thrown, I am expecting the message to be requeued.  I believe that I have all the conditions met for this as I gleaned from this [post](http://forum.spring.io/forum/spring-projects/integration/amqp/128005-setting-basic-reject-with-requeue-true-using-amqp-inbound-channel-adapter)

In the post, I learned that there are three conditions to ensure a requeue:
1) The `acknowledge-mode` must be AUTO.
2) The `requeue-rejected` must be TRUE.
3) Throw any exception BUT `AmqpRejectAndDontRequeueException`.

I believe I am meeting these conditions in some test code that I wrote:

**Configuration**

The service activator is where an exception is thrown that does not inherit from `AmqpRejectAndDontRequeueException`

```
@Autowired
public void setSpringIntegrationConfigHelper (SpringIntegrationHelper springIntegrationConfig) {
    this.springIntegrationConfigHelper = springIntegrationConfig;   
}

@Bean
public String priorityPOCQueueName() {
    return "poc.priority";
}

@Bean
public Queue priorityPOCQueue(RabbitAdmin rabbitAdmin) {
    Queue queue = new Queue(priorityPOCQueueName(), true);
    rabbitAdmin.declareQueue(queue);
    return queue;
}

@Bean
public Binding priorityPOCQueueBinding(RabbitAdmin rabbitAdmin) {
    Binding binding = new Binding(priorityPOCQueueName(),
                                  DestinationType.QUEUE,
                                  "amq.direct",
                                  priorityPOCQueue(rabbitAdmin).getName(),
                                  null);
    rabbitAdmin.declareBinding(binding);
    return binding;
}

@Bean
public AmqpTemplate priorityPOCMessageTemplate(ConnectionFactory amqpConnectionFactory,
                                                @Qualifier("priorityPOCQueueName") String queueName,
                                                @Qualifier("jsonMessageConverter") MessageConverter messageConverter) {
    RabbitTemplate template = new RabbitTemplate(amqpConnectionFactory);
    template.setChannelTransacted(false);
    template.setExchange("amq.direct");
    template.setQueue(queueName);
    template.setRoutingKey(queueName);
    template.setMessageConverter(messageConverter);
    return template;
}


@Autowired
@Qualifier("priorityPOCQueue")
public void setPriorityPOCQueue(Queue priorityPOCQueue) {
    this.priorityPOCQueue = priorityPOCQueue;
}

@Bean(name="exec.priorityPOC")
TaskExecutor taskExecutor() {
    ThreadPoolTaskExecutor e = new ThreadPoolTaskExecutor();
    e.setCorePoolSize(1);
    e.setQueueCapacity(1);
    return e;
}

@Bean(name="poc.priorityChannel")
public MessageChannel pocPriorityChannel() {
    PriorityChannel c = new PriorityChannel(new PriorityComparator());
    c.setComponentName("poc.priorityChannel");
    c.setBeanName("poc.priorityChannel");
    return c;
}

@Bean(name="poc.inboundChannelAdapter") //make this a unique name
public AmqpInboundChannelAdapter amqpInboundChannelAdapter(@Qualifier("exec.priorityPOC") TaskExecutor taskExecutor
        , @Qualifier("poc.errorChannel") MessageChannel pocErrorChannel) {

    int concurrentConsumers = 1;
    AmqpInboundChannelAdapter a =  mimediaSpringIntegrationConfigHelper.createInboundChannelAdapter(taskExecutor
            , pocPriorityChannel(), new Queue[]{priorityPOCQueue},  concurrentConsumers);
    a.setErrorChannel(pocErrorChannel);
    return a;

}

@ServiceActivator(inputChannel="poc.priorityChannel")
public void processUserFileCollectionAudit(@Header(SimulateErrorHeaderPostProcessor.ERROR_SIMULATE_HEADER_KEY) Boolean simulateError, PriorityMessage priorityMessage) throws InterruptedException {
    if (isFirstMessageReceived == false) {
        Thread.sleep(15000); //Cause a bit of a backup so we can see prioritizing in action.
        isFirstMessageReceived = true;
    }
    logger.debug("Received message with priority: " + priorityMessage.getPriority() + ", simulateError: " + simulateError +  ", Current retry count is "
        + priorityMessage.getRetryCount());
    if (simulateError && priorityMessage.getRetryCount() < PriorityMessage.MAX_MESSAGE_RETRY_COUNT) {
        logger.debug(" Simulating an error and re-queue'ng. Current retry count is " + priorityMessage.getRetryCount());
        priorityMessage.setRetryCount(priorityMessage.getRetryCount() + 1);
        throw new NonAdequateResourceException();
    } else if (simulateError && priorityMessage.getRetryCount() >= PriorityMessage.MAX_MESSAGE_RETRY_COUNT) {
        logger.debug(" Max retry count exceeded");
    }
}
```

**SpringIntegrationHelper**

This is where auto acknowledge and requeue rejected are being set.

```
protected ConnectionFactory connectionFactory;
protected MessageChannel errorChannel;
protected MessageConverter messageConverter;

@Autowired
public void setConnectionFactory (ConnectionFactory connectionFactory) {
    this.connectionFactory = connectionFactory;
}

@Autowired
public void setErrorChannel(MessageChannel errorChannel) {
    this.errorChannel = errorChannel;
}

@Autowired
public void setMessageConverter(@Qualifier("jsonMessageConverter") MessageConverter messageConverter) {
    this.messageConverter = messageConverter;
}

public AmqpInboundChannelAdapter createInboundChannelAdapter(TaskExecutor taskExecutor
        ,  MessageChannel outputChannel, Queue[] queues, int concurrentConsumers) {
    SimpleMessageListenerContainer listenerContainer =
            new SimpleMessageListenerContainer(connectionFactory);
    //AUTO is default, but setting it anyhow.
    listenerContainer.setAcknowledgeMode(AcknowledgeMode.AUTO);
    listenerContainer.setAutoStartup(true);
    listenerContainer.setConcurrentConsumers(concurrentConsumers);
    listenerContainer.setMessageConverter(messageConverter);
    listenerContainer.setQueues(queues);
    //listenerContainer.setChannelTransacted(false);
    listenerContainer.setPrefetchCount(100);
    listenerContainer.setTaskExecutor(taskExecutor);
    listenerContainer.setDefaultRequeueRejected(true);



    AmqpInboundChannelAdapter a = new AmqpInboundChannelAdapter(listenerContainer);
    a.setMessageConverter(messageConverter);
    a.setAutoStartup(true);
    //TODO This was stopping my custom error handler. Fix. a.setErrorChannel(errorChannel);
    a.setHeaderMapper(MimediaAmqpHeaderMapper.createPassAllHeaders());
    a.setOutputChannel(outputChannel);
    return a;
}
```

Why are my messages not being re-queued?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

4) The exception has to be thrown on the listener's thread.

It will only work if the exception is thrown on the listener container thread that received the message.

Since you are using a `PriorityChannel` as the output channel of the adapter, you are immediately handing the message off to another thread so there is no exception on the listener thread and the message is always ack'd.

Comment: Thanks, obviously I completely missed that; explains it perfectly. I have a follow on question, but that should probably be posted as a separate question rather than carrying on a conversation in this comments section. I will compose another post.